# Are Google App Engine A/AAAA records fixed?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The process for mapping a custom domain to an app engine project is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)

The final step is updating your DNS configuration with the records (ip addresses) generated by Google.

My question is - are these records static? Put another way are the values always

> **for naked domains**
>
> A           216.239.32.21
>
> A            216.239.34.21
>
> A            216.239.36.21
>
> A.          216.239.38.21
>
> AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::15
>
> AAAA   2001:4860:4802:34::15
>
> AAAA   2001:4860:4802:36::15
>
> AAAA  2001:4860:4802:38::15

and

> **for www (or subdomains)**
>
> CNAME.    ghs.googlehosted.com.

I'm asking because if these values are fixed, then I should be able to add them to the DNS at the same that I'm adding the values (TXT or CNAME) for domain ownership verification.

Comment: Yes, above mentioned IP Addresses are static (to google, not to ur app. these are shared). But nothing is permenant, should there be a change in the addresses, google will communicate and give time to change to new IP address.

Answer (score 4):

DNS servers do not know nor care if an IP address is fixed/static. You can enter any valid number that you want. Of course, you need to enter valid information for DNS to resolve correctly.

The IP addresses for App Engine are Global IP addresses. The address assigned to your service does not change, therefore you can call them "fixed" or "static".

For additional details. These IP addresses are not actually assigned to your service. Instead, they represent the address of the Google Frontend (GFE), a type of proxy load balancer. Numerous other services will also have the same IP address. The HTTP header `host` is used to route traffic to the correct service.

Comment: Yes, I understand they are not assigned to my service (i.e. app). I was trying to confirm those values are for all intents and purposes fixed and always resolve to GAE. Thanks

Comment: hi john, thank you for the answer. GCP is asking to add A and CNAME records that have the same name, but that's not possible. For example I cannot add subdomain.domain.com as the name for both CNAME and A record at the same time. What should be done in this case?

Comment: @RobertSinclair - For the naked domain you must use A/AAAA DNS resource records. For subdomains, you can use either A/AAAA or CNAME but not both types.  CNAMES are more convenient but A/AAAA are faster. Just to clarify the original question is `Are Google App Engine A/AAAA records fixed?`.