# App Engine > Subdomain > Add A, AAAA and CNAME record

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it okey to add the A and AAAA records but not the CNAME record when adding a **subdomain** to App Engine?

Read the following SO threads, but couldn't find the answer:

[Custom Subdomain for Google App Engine Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576228/custom-subdomain-for-google-app-engine-service?rq=2)

[Are Google App Engine A/AAAA records fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58357461/are-google-app-engine-a-aaaa-records-fixed?rq=2)

[Adding Google-managed, auto-renewing SSL custom domain with cloudflare DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917498/adding-google-managed-auto-renewing-ssl-custom-domain-with-cloudflare-dns?rq=2)

[URL Not Found - Adding a Custom Domain - GCP App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75116753/url-not-found-adding-a-custom-domain-gcp-app-engine?rq=2)

[App Engine Custom Domain Mapping Issue: Domain not mapping to App Engine services after 48 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76068452/app-engine-custom-domain-mapping-issue-domain-not-mapping-to-app-engine-service?rq=2)

https://serverfault.com/questions/849637/add-a-aaaa-and-cname-record-for-google-app-engine-project-in-google-cloud-plat (most similar to my question, but also didn't provide a valid answer)

### Breakdown:

I have a subdomain (*subdomain.domain.com*) when adding it to App Engine it tell me to add these records:

[image]

I added the A and AAAA records, but get an error when adding the CNAME record..

I read that I cannot have an A record and a CNAME record with the same host (example *subdomain.domain.com*).

Does that mean that I don't have to add the CNAME record or do I need to add it differently?

I read the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?csw=1#dns_update and several questions on SO, but it's still unclear unfortunately.

### What the custom subdomain settings are supposed to look like

subdomain.mydomain.com -> AppEngine

the naked domain mydomain.com does **not** point to AppEngine

### Update

Spoke to Google support and they said that the **name** of the CNAME record can be **subdomain.subdomain.domain.com** instead of **subdomain.domain.com**, but it doesn't seem to make sense :-/

Comment: updated the question, think the downvote came because i mentioned cPanel, I removed that mention. This question applies to other scenarios also.

Comment: It _seems_ your question is only about `CNAME`. In short, you don't need a `CNAME`. But for what is worth, I recommend you read this [brief about `CNAME`s](https://support.google.com/a/answer/112037?hl=en&ref_topic=1687211&sjid=13805682362224865441-NA#zippy=%2Cset-up-cname-records-now).

Comment: Thank you Jetto. I thought it's used for load balancing. I'm trying to confirm with Google support but it's 500$/month.

Comment: Not sure why the question is getting downvoted, this is something others may experience also. In GCP it says we need to add both CNAME, A and AAAA records with the same host, but that's not possible. Think it could be useful for other who run into this issue.

Comment: Where in the docs says so? I did something similar, but on a way smaller scale, and it didn't mention `CNAME`. I actually had to research it independently, and before that, I didn't have it (For a solid year, at least).

Comment: Actually, how are your domains supposed to look? Could you add it to the question? You are trying something like, `mydomain.com` (A/AAAA) -> AppEngine1, `www.mydomain.com` (CNAME) -> AppEngine1, right?

Comment: @JettoMartínez sure, i just updated the question. I got it to work without CNAME pointing to the actual subdomain, so i think what you said is right, it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding all the A records and AAAA records to the subdomain and the CNAME record was added like this (as per Google support suggestion).

```
www.subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.subdomain.com
```

It doesn't seem right, but in app engine settings page it shows that everything is setup correctly.

Interestingly enough Facebook even recommends to NOT setup the CNAME at all

[image]